# spacing between the items of a tasks list

Tags: line-spacing, exsheets, tasks

I thought I managed to solve this by tweaking the 'after-item-skip', 'after-skip' &Co settings of the `tasks` package but I ran into some unexpected issues with page breaks when the number of tasks gets higher. Given I had to use some negative values, I think I didn't do it right.

Can anybody help with the proper way to solve the problem in the MWE below? I.e suggesting the right way to set the **spacings** (and the indentation of list items if it's not much to ask) *only* in 'Part 1' of the code so that the output will be more or less as the output of 'Part 2'. The spacing between the last 3 lines is fine, I just put those lines to make sure the solution doesn't break that.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{exsheets}

\usepackage{tasks}

\usepackage{parskip}


\SetupExSheets{headings = empty}


\begin{document}


Part 1

\begin{question}OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO\\OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO

\begin{tasks}
   \task OOOOOOOOOOOOO
   \task OOOOOOOOOOOOO
\end{tasks}
\settasks{resume = true}
\begin{tasks}
 \task OOOOOOOOOOOOO
 \task OOOOOOOOOOOOO
\end{tasks}

\end{question}
\begin{question}
    OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO\\
    OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
\end{question}
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO

=================

Part 2

\par I need to make the above text \\
to look [exactly] like this:\\
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO\\OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO\\
a) OOOOOOOOOOOOO\\
b) OOOOOOOOOOOOO\\
c) OOOOOOOOOOOOO\\
d) OOOOOOOOOOOOO
\par OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO\\OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
\par OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
\end{document}
```

Comment: I need to set the spacings in Part 1 only (i.e. no alterations to the Part 2). I'd really appreciate an MWE (no output) so there's no misunderstanding from my part. Thanks

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: Even if it did, the spacing between the 2 tasks environments (where `\settasks{resume = true}` comes in) was unaffected (and it's not as it should be). I need 2 (or more) tasks environments one after the other as I need to change the number of columns within the question environment (from 4 to 3 to 2 for example)

Comment: Can you post an example of that so that I can try it? In my trials, I could manage the spacing.

Comment: An example is right in the MWE I posted in the question. Please include your code in it and post the entire modified MWE so anyone can run it and see that the 2 Parts are identical (except the indentation of `\task`s maybe).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\SetupExSheets{headings = empty}
\usepackage{parskip}

\settasks{
  % the next two should be set to the same value so labels are aligned to the
  % left
  label-width = 1em ,
  item-indent = 1em ,
  before-skip = -\parskip , % undo paragraph skip
  after-skip = -\parskip , % undo paragraph skip
  after-item-skip = -\parskip % undo paragraph skip
}

\begin{document}

Part 1

\begin{question}OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO\\OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
\begin{tasks}
   \task OOOOOOOOOOOOO
   \task OOOOOOOOOOOOO
\end{tasks}
\vspace{\parskip}
\begin{tasks}[resume]
 \task OOOOOOOOOOOOO
 \task OOOOOOOOOOOOO
\end{tasks}
\end{question}
\begin{question}
    OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO\\
    OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
\end{question}
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO

Part 2

I need to make the above text \\
to look [exactly] like this:\\
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO\\OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO\\
a) OOOOOOOOOOOOO\\
b) OOOOOOOOOOOOO\\
c) OOOOOOOOOOOOO\\
d) OOOOOOOOOOOOO
\par OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO\\OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
\par OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Beat me to it by one minute. `:-(`

Comment: @cgnieder Now that's looking great! I'm sure this is the way to do it (never thought to use/reverse `\parskip`) - it looks right and coming from the package author...   I'll have to test this in my complicated and over_nested code and see what happens (I suspect it will be ok).    One note though (same thing in my code) - when the `task` reaches "m", the m character being too wide for the space (I presume), I get a log error "bad box" ... "Overfull \hbox (x pt) in paragraph".

Comment: Well, you can always increase the label width

Comment: @cgnieder I tried the other day, no joy. Tried label alignment, no good result. I will have to try again though, please don't mind it for now. Back to Q. I tried your settings in my code (where all the tasks are math inline equations and where "Part 2" is another `question` environment). Didn't work as expected (perhaps I have another `parskip` mod somewhere - I need to check) but I removed the `after-skip` tweak and everything fell into place very nice. The big clue in your answer was to reverse the `parskip`. Now the pagebrakes work as they should. Thank you!