# Unwanted vertical whitespace after 'tasks' environments

Tags: tasks

I'm using the `tasks` package to build a set of math tests.  Some of the problems need to be in one column, and some of them need to be in multiple columns, so I'm using separate `tasks` environments.  However, every time I end one `tasks` environment and start a new one, I end up with some extra vertical whitespace that I don't want.  Case in point:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}

\NewTasks[
counter-format={tsk[1].}, 
label-format=\bfseries,
label-width=0.25in,
label-align=right,
label-offset=0.1in,
item-indent=0.35in, 
after-item-skip=10pt, 
resume=true
]{problems}[\prob]

\begin{document}
  \begin{problems}
    \prob Single-column problem 1
    \prob Problem 2
  \end{problems}
  \begin{problems}(2)
    \prob Double-column problems
    \prob Problem 4
  \end{problems}
\end{document}
```

[image: example image - unwanted vertical whitespace]

Where is this whitespace coming from?  And what's the best way to get rid of it?  Should I set `after-skip` to a negative value?  How much?  I'm using ShareLaTeX, by the way, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Please, make your code compilable. The preamble is missing.

Comment: Not all but the minimal ones so we can copy and paste your code to test it.

Comment: Sorry about that.

Comment: There is an extra `6pt plus 2pt minus 4pt` between the lists (seen via using `\showoutput`), which you can remove by inserting `\vspace{-6pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}` between the lists. But perhaps there's a better, automated way of doing this.

Comment: You can use a single `problems` environment with two-column layout and use `\prob!` for items spanning both columns, as in:   `\begin{problems}(2)
    \prob! Single-column problem 1
    \prob! Problem 2
    \prob Double-column problems
    \prob Problem 4
  \end{problems}`

Comment: Thanks!  @Werner how do you use `\showoutput` like that?

Comment: @JosephMontanaro: Add it to your document (wherever) and check the `.log` file. It will include all the pages that are shipped out from wherever you place `\showoutput` in a nested/boxed fashion. You can interpret the `\glue` that is inserted, the characters and from which font... all nifty, garbled stuff.

Comment: Without a working MWE, I think you should try `after-skip = -\parskip , % undo paragraph skip`) as suggested in this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/208060/43189

Comment: Use the updated version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is no longer a problem in the up to date version of `tasks`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}[2022-01-08]

\NewTasksEnvironment[
  label = \arabic*. , 
  label-format = \bfseries ,
  label-width = 0.25in ,
  label-align = right ,
  label-offset = 0.1in ,
  item-indent = 0.35in , 
  after-item-skip = \topsep, 
  resume=true
]{problems}[\prob]

\begin{document}

\begin{problems}
  \prob Single-column problem 1
  \prob Problem 2
\end{problems}
\begin{problems}(2)
  \prob Double-column problems
  \prob Problem 4
\end{problems}

Or:
\begin{problems}(2)
  \prob* Single-column problem 1
  \prob* Problem 2
  \prob Double-column problems
  \prob Problem 4
\end{problems}

\end{document}
```

[image]